# Como saber si una pagina recibe post

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

En una pagina .aspx (**detail_page.aspx**) tengo un código como este, ahora más abajo agregue un formulario HTML con action a la misma pagina.

¿Cómo puedo saber si la página está recibiendo el post o NO?

El objetivo es si recibe el post ejecutar un código y si no lo recibe ejecutar este código que ya tengo:

```
<%
         int restaurantId = 0;
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
             if(Session["idrestaurant"]!= null)
             {
                 int.TryParse(Session["idrestaurant"].ToString(), out restaurantId);
             }
             hfRestaurantId.Value = restaurantId.ToString();//Set restaurantId 
         }

         SaborWebApp.restaurant rest = new SaborWebApp.SaborEntities().restaurant.Where(a => a.RestaurantID == restaurantId).FirstOrDefault();
     %>
```

**Formulario Html**

```
<form method="post" action="../Delivery/detail_page.aspx" name="review" id="review" class="popup-form" /> 

 <input name="name_review" id="name_review" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control form-white" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-submit" id="submit-review"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente tengas que usar el

[Request.HttpMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)

en conjunto con el

[HttpRequest.Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx)

para obtener el dato del input text

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop); lo instalas para poder consumir los datos y hacer las pruebas.

Comment: ayudaría mucho que edites la respuesta colocando un pequeño ejemplo de cómo usar Postman, caso contrario la respuesta quedaría como candidata a ser eliminada por 'baja calidad' debido a su extensión y contenido. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Algo asi :

```
  <%
    var metodo = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod;
    string nameReview, emailReview, textReview;
    decimal foodReview, priceReview, punctualityReview, courtesyReview;
    int verifyReview;
    switch (metodo.ToLower())
    {
        case "post":
            NameValueCollection nameValue = Request.Form;
            if (nameValue.Count > 0)
            {
                nameReview = nameValue["nameReview"].ToString();
                emailReview = nameValue["emailReview "].ToString();
                foodReview = Convert.ToDecimal(nameValue["foodReview"]);
                priceReview = Convert.ToDecimal(nameValue["priceReview"]);
                punctualityReview = Convert.ToDecimal(nameValue["punctualityReview"]);
                courtesyReview = Convert.ToDecimal(nameValue["courtesyReview"]);
                textReview = nameValue["textReview"].ToString();
                verifyReview = Convert.ToInt32(nameValue["verifyReview"]);
                SaborWebApp.Engine.EngineRestaurant Sp = new  SaborWebApp.Engine.EngineRestaurant();
                bool resultadoInsert = Sp.InsertRestaurantReview((int)Session["idRestaurant"], (int)Session["idCliente"], nameReview, textReview, (int) , foodReview, priceReview, punctualityReview, courtesyReview, 0, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);

            }
            break;
        case "get":
            if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
            {
                Session["idRestaurant"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["idRestaurant"]);
                Session["idCliente"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["idCliente"]);
                Session["idOrder"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["idOrder"]);
            }
            break;
    }
%>
```